Known Extensions of the Exponential Factorial
Tetration is the name given to iterated exponentation, basically it is a function that satisfies $$f(0)=1$$ & $$f(z+1)=b^{f(z)}$$ for some base $b\in\mathbb{R}$. If $b>e^{1/e}$ it has been shown there is a unique holomorphic function which satisfies said eqaution. I was wondering if there is an analogous function for the factorial as tetration is to exponentation. That is, if there is a function that satisfies $$f(0)=1$$ & $$f(z+1)=(z+1)^{f(z)}.$$ To simplify things a little one can instead consider $g(z)=f(z-1)$ which will satisfy $g(1)=0$ and $$g(z+1)=z^{g(z)}.$$ This function may be called the exponential gamma function. Now I wish to extend the domain of $g$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{C}$, some conditions I'd like this function to satisfy is that it is infinitely differentiable. I've searched online for any possible solutions to the problem but have came up empty handed. It may be just that such a function is beyond the reach of any current methods, but if there are any ways to create such a function even if it is not unique, I'd like to know.

It is probably difficult to find an extension to $\mathbb C$ since $\log$ cannot be defined as a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C$.

Yes, maybe not to all of $\mathbb{C}$, but if there's an extension to most of the complex plane minus a branch cut that's what I'd be looking for. Similar to tetration, where there's a branch cut $-2$. However; it does seem that the exponential gamma (abbreviate, EG) function carries a lot less information, for example with the gamma function you can conclude from the recursive definition that at negative integers it must be undefined, but with the EG function it seems f(0) could be chosen arbitrarily.
